# How to calcualate Ethereum transaction fee

Tags: ether, gas-price

I have got 1 Ether in a account, which I would like to empty the account by sending to some other account. May I know the calculation that how much have to be subtracted from 1 ether and send to some other account.

Note: this calculation should work for any no of ether to be transferred

Answer (score 3):

[This site](https://ethgasstation.info/index.php) is pretty useful to calculate Ether transaction price and giving current gas price. Median and recommended gas price varies depending on several things.

With the current standard gas price (9 GWei), 21000 gas is about 0.00019 Eth. With current rates, it totals to about $0.14.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re doing a straight ether transfer (as opposed to say a smart contract call) the price in gas is 21000 gas. Multiply that by the gasPrice you’re willing to pay and you’ll get the number in ether you’ll pay. You choose the gasPrice, so there’s no fixed answer. If you’re calling a smart contract, then it depends on the contract and the call you make.